# Where am I going wrong in this change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Given the matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 \\ -1 & 4\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the vector
$$
b = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}
$$
I want to find the vector $x$ such that $Ax = b$, i.e. I want to find the vector equivalent to $b$ expressed using the basis in $A$. Normally, this would be done using a simple inverse:
\begin{align}
x &= A^{-1}b \\
&= \frac{1}{17} \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -1 \\ 1 & 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{17} \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 14\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

However, I want to find $x$ "graphically" by projecting $x$ onto the basis vectors

\begin{align}
v_1 &= \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -1\end{bmatrix} \\
v_2 &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

I would then compute
\begin{align}
x_1 &= b \cdot \frac{v_1}{||v_1||} \\
x_2 &= b \cdot \frac{v_2}{||v_2||}
\end{align}
such that
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
However, I do not get the same answer above. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Am I missing something or did you not use the vector $b$ *at all* in your second method?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that is a typo, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dot the equation $b=x_1v_1+x_2v_2$ with $v_1$, you get $x_1=\dfrac{b\cdot v_1}{\|v_1\|^2}$. Dotting with the unit vector isn’t good enough; do you see why?

Comment: I can see how you got to your expression for $x_1$, but I am not sure how to relate this to my graphical procedure. The reason I am dotting $b$ with the normalized version of $v_1$ is that I know that $$b \cdot \frac{v_1}{||v_1||} = ||b|| \cos \theta$$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $b$ and $v_1$. Since $||b|| \cos \theta$ is the length of $b$ along $v_1$, then surely it must be that $$\left(b \cdot \frac{v_1}{||v_1||}\right)v_1 + \left(b \cdot \frac{v_2}{||v_2||}\right)v_2 = b$$ correct?

Comment: No, it’s the length along the unit vector, not the multiple of the actual $v_1$. Try it with a vector of length $2$.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. What should be right then is $$\left(b \cdot \frac{v_1}{||v_1||}\right)\frac{v_1}{||v_1||} + \left(b \cdot \frac{v_2}{||v_2||}\right)\frac{v_2}{||v_2||} = b$$ correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct! And, of course, this agrees with my original formula. :) Great that you’re working to understand the geometry!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You’re welcome. If it interests you, you might find some of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) of help. More proofs and geometry.